# Find and replace - Regular Expressions

Tags: eclipse, css

As IE10 has come out and they are not using prefixes for animations nor keyframes I have decided to remove them from my project. It is a very large project so I did not want to have to remove lines manually. Here is an example of what I would like to remove:

```
@-ms-keyframes fadestars {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    25% { opacity: 0.2; }
    30% { opacity: 1; }
    50% { opacity: 0.2;}
    55% { opacity: 1; }
    60% { opacity: 0.2; }
    65% { opacity: 1; }
    75% { opacity: 0.5; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

-ms-animation: fadestars 30s linear 1s infinite;
```

So I would like to remove these, I know I will need 2 different expressions to remove them. The one I tried for the keyframe was the following:

```
-ms-keyframes(.*?\{[.\n]*?\})
```

This was not successful, anyone with knowledge of regular expressions within eclipse that could help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered my own question. So I hope that this helps anyone. The code below can be used to search for any keyframes for -ms- (this prefix could be changed for -moz- too as freom v16 of firefox they are no longer needed) and can help remove them from your own project. Saved me a lot of time

```
@-ms-keyframes \w+ \{\R(.|\R)*?\R\}
```

Comment: I was about to + you just because you got the regex before me, however it seems this regex can find larger part of the file from time to time, watch out not to remove something crucial

Comment: ah ok, if you have a better answer to give then i will accept yours. It did work for me where i had line returns after my first open bracket but not if it was all on one line